# Good Oracle database development and management tool on Windows

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracleclient

I'm looking for an Oracle database management tool like sql server management studio.
I've searched the internet and found a lot of tools on the following link:

http://www.freedownloadscenter.com/Search/oracle.html.

But I don't know which one is better.

I need a stable and easy-to-use GUI tool for working on windows.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The best free ones are (in no particular order)

- [SQL Developer](http://www.oracle.com/technology/products/database/sql_developer/index.html)
- [TOra](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tora/)
- [TOAD](http://toadfororacle.com/index.jspa)
- [Oracle Enterprise Manager](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10713/cncptdba.htm#CHDHBAAI) (parts are included in the licence)
- [Eclipse plugin - SQL Explorer](http://eclipsesql.sourceforge.net/)

The best commercial ones are (in no particular order)

- [TOAD](http://toadfororacle.com/index.jspa)
- [DBArtisan](http://www.embarcadero.com/products/dbartisan-xe)
- [Oracle Enterprise Manager](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10713/cncptdba.htm#CHDHBAAI)
- [PL/SQL Developer](http://www.allroundautomations.com/plsqldev.html)

Comment: Thanks. It's useful. Why 2k views and only 5 upvotes...

Answer (score 6):

My shop uses an open-source Eclipse plugin called SQL Explorer: http://eclipsesql.sourceforge.net/  It has good stuff for examining schemata; it integrates with your source code control system; it works on other database table servers too.

We also use a commercial tool called PL/SQL Developer: http://www.allroundautomations.com/plsqldev.html
This tool has a "SQL Beautifier" which can tidy up some of the hairiest queries you can imagine.  In tidying them up, it helps the one writing the query find typos.  It also has a context menu that will do "EXPLAIN PLAN" on a query that's already running, and a way to stop a running query.  Those are incredibly handy tools.

Carpenteri mentioned Oracle Enterprise Manager.  That comes with your Oracle thick client.  I find it helpful for getting an instance-wide view of what's going on in your server.

Comment: I'd also recommend PL/SQL Developer saved me hours when debugging stored procs. Never had to use any other Oracle tools while developing once I got this :-)

Comment: +1 for PL/SQL DEveloper. Fantastic tool.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a system management tool for your Oracle database it is worth looking at the [Oracle Enterprise Manager](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10713/cncptdba.htm#CHDHBAAI)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a combination of some tools like SQL Developer, SQLTools and [Aqua Data Studio](http://www.aquafold.com)